# Failed in clear the route of the Direction Service in Google Map API 3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-directions-api

When i click a button to reset the map by clearing the marker and the direction route, i am not sure the user have already created the route or not. My function will be dead if the following codes are included during the Click Event. But it worked properly if these three codes are removed...

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
```

Is it necessary to determine whether the directionsDisplay are null or not before executing the aforesaid codes? My codings are extracted below for your advice... Many thanks...

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var StartMarker = null;
var EndMarker = null;
var directionsVisible = false;
var oldDirections = [];
var currentDirections = null;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    if (!StartMarker) {
        origin = event.latLng;

        lat = origin.lat();
        lng = origin.lng();
        /*If the origin is null, run UpdateLatLng() function to convert 
          the Lat, Lng of the mouse click position to Northing, Easting and
          assign the value to the textbox */
        UpdateLatLng();

        var startimage = 'images/Start4.png';
        StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: origin,
            icon: startimage
        });
    } else {
        //Relocate the Starting point and assign the new position to Textbox
        alert ("The starting point was relocated on screen"); 
        StartMarker.setMap(null);
        if (EndMarker !==null) {
            EndMarker.setMap(null);
        };
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
        var origin = event.latLng;
        lat = origin.lat();
        lng = origin.lng();
        UpdateLatLng();
        //StartMarker.setPosition(origin.getposition());
        var startimage = 'images/Start4.png';
        StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: origin,
            icon: startimage
        });
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',
        function() {
            if (currentDirections) {
                oldDirections.push(currentDirections);
                setUndoDisabled(false);
            }
            currentDirections = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
            calcRoute();
        });
function calcRoute() {
    if (origin == null) {
        alert("Please input the starting point");
        return;
    }

    var mode;
    switch (document.getElementById("mode").value) {
        case "driving":
            mode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
            break;
        case "walking":
            mode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
            break;
        case "transit":
            mode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT;
            break;
    }

    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: waypoints,
        travelMode: mode,
        optimizeWaypoints: document.getElementById('optimize').checked,
        avoidHighways: document.getElementById('highways').checked,
        avoidTolls: document.getElementById('tolls').checked
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        }
    });

    directionsVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the programming language you've used, both for the sake of tagging and syntax highlighting. While you're at it fix your code indentation.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice.. Hope that the problem can be fixed...

Comment: What is currentDirections?  That is undefined in your code, as is UpdateLatLng.

Comment: Thanks... currentDirections are defined in the beginning of the html and i just added it again in the coding above.. UpdateLatLng function is another function that are not relevant to the direcitonsService...
All other functions in this project worked properly except i can't remove the route when i click on the map.

Comment: Might not be relevant to the directions service, but your code fails without it...

Comment: I have another 'Reset' button that have the aforementioned code to clear the route and it works properly... I really don't know why it is not worked in the Map Click listener....

Comment: Finally... i fix the problem by another syntax...
   if(directionsDisplay != null) {
   directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
   directionsDisplay = null;
   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is fixed by adopting the following codes...

```
 if(directionsDisplay != null) { 
   directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
   directionsDisplay = null; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
map.setZoom(8);
map.setCenter();
```